# Total Hours worked in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to compute my exact pay with the total hours worked in a spreadsheet.  I have one cell that is computing my number of hours worked, which is working fine, but when I go to add them all together I get 0.00.  I am using =SUM(D2:D8) and get 0.00,  Is this because I have a formula in those cells calculating the number of hours worked? The formula in D Cells is

```
=IF(C3<B3,C3+1,C3)-B3
```

Included is a snipit of the excel sheet, please note I am just starting this which is why there's not alot of information in it...

[image]

Comment: Format your total cell `[hh]:mm`  It will then show `48:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum adds up to 2 days and zero hours, but your formatting for cell F7 is returning only the hour portion of that sum.

You can check this by increasing one of the out times by an hour.  The sum will then show 1:00.

So, use this formula for the sum:

```
=24*SUM(D2:D8)
```

and format the result as a number.

Comment: Bandersnatch! Thank you infinity times Infinity!!! That worked.

Comment: Infinity squared is a lot! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the total (SUM) formula isn't in the same format as the time entries. An easy fix would be:

1. Copy any cell from the time entries.
2. Right-click on the total cell (sum formula, in this case, cell F7).
3. From the sub menu, in the *Paste Options*, click **formatting**. That will just paste the *format* to your formula.